# Stopping infinite loops while running clojure tests in emacs with leiningen and swank/slime

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, leiningen, swank

In certain kinds of code it's relatively easy to cause an infinite loop without blowing the stack.  When testing code of this nature using clojure-test, is there a way to abort the current running tests without restarting the swank server?

Currently my workflow has involved

```
$ lein swank
```

Connect to swank with emacs using `slime-connect`, and switch to the the tests, execute with `C-c C-,`, tests run until infinite loop, then just return but one cpu is still churning away on the test.  The only way to stop this I have found is to restart lein swank, but it seems like this would be a relatively common problem?  Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is a common problem for programmers to write infinite loops in development :). And the answer is very simple. It's called "Interrupt Command" and it is `C-c C-b`

Leiningen has nothing to do with this. This is SLIME/Swank/Clojure. When you evaluate code in Emacs you are spawning a new thread within Clojure. SLIME keeps reference to those threads and shows you how many are running in the Emacs modeline. If you're in a graphical environment you can click the modeline where it indicates your namespace and see lots of options. One option is "Interrupt Command"

Eval `(while true)` and `C-c C-b` to get a dialog showing a `java.lang.ThreadDeath` error with probably just one option. You can type `0` or `q` to quit that thread, kill that error message buffer and return focus to your previous buffer.

Comment: It is bound to cider-interrupt in CIDER and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this old discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/clojure/vP1zacPwBSE/vpUon4_f8eQJ), adding `(use 'clojure.contrib.repl-utils))` and `(add-break-thread!)` to user.clj should enable you to press `C-c C-c` for passing SIGINT to the long running evaluation/processe.

Comment: My current Emacs setup binds `C-c C-c` to `slime-interrupt` which behaves as you would expect

Answer (score 1):

if all else fails.. `alt-x slime-quit-lisp` and restart the REPL. try Psyllo's answer first of course.